# Dynamically assign positions for axis labels

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is it possible to dynamically assign positions for axis labels in Microsoft Excel (Office 365 Pro Plus)?

I am building a timeline with ramifications going up and down because I have a lot of text in the labels.

Is it possible to put some axis labels below and some above the axis? (see image)

[image]

Like some sort of parameter:

```
1935    -1
1950    1
1962    -1
1992    1
```